# Dynamically Generating ViewFlippers

Tags: android, dynamic, viewflipper

After quite a bit of technical jiggery-pokery I am finally able to read an XML file from elsewhere on the Web and display the contained data.

This XML file is actually a description of a location (including lat/long coords) and the pinball machines you could find at that location.

So what I want to do now is this:
There are several classes of notes contained in the XML, notes about the location itself and notes about the individual pinball machines.
I would like to isolate these groups of notes into separate views and make them accessible from the main display page. There would be a button or something reading '3 comments' or something similar which would trigger the ViewFlipper.

Since I have no idea how many notes of either type I would be loading from any of the 1300+ XML pages (and there could be no notes at all!), it makes sense that I would have to dynamically generate these views at runtime.

Would ViewFlipper in fact be a good choice for this kind of operation or am I completely off-base here?

I thank you in advance for your time in sorting this out.